# Get one maximum value per group

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I need to preserve one row per group of names from table:

```
ID | Name  | Attribute1| Attribute2 | Attribute3
 1 | john  | true      | 2012-20-10 | 12345670
 2 | john  | false     | 2015-20-10 | 12345671
 3 | james | false     | 2010-02-01 | 12345672
 4 | james | false     | 2010-02-03 | 12345673
 5 | james | false     | 2010-02-06 | 12345674
 6 | sara  | true      | 2011-02-02 | 12345675
 7 | sara  | true      | 2011-02-02 | 12345676
```

...according to specified criteria. In first place should be preserved rows with true in Attribute1 (if present), then with max date (Attribute2), and if that's not result in one row - the one with max Attribute3.

Desired result is:

```
ID|Name|Attribute1|Attribute2|Attribute3
1 | john  | true  | 2012-20-10 | 12345670
5 | james | false | 2010-02-06 | 12345674
7 | sara  | true  | 2011-02-02 | 12345676
```

I tried to do that with nested joins, but that seems to be overly complicated. 
Some simply solution is to first do the SQL result of ORDER BY:

```
CREATE TABLE output AS
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Name,
    Attribute1,
    Attribute2,
    Attribute3
FROM input 
ORDER BY 
    Name,
    Attribute1 DESC, 
    Attribute2 DESC, 
    Attribute3 DESC;
```

and do the loop for each row and check and cache if name occurred before - if not, preserve it (and cache name in some global variable), else delete row.

Is there any other pure SQL solution?

Comment: "*In first place should be preserved rows with true in Attribute1*" - that contradicts your desired result, because there is a row with `attribute1 = false`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I started with sqlite, as I needed quick solution without need to install postgresql - but eventually, it might be any database. It cannot be attribute1 = true, because if all of the rows in group have false on Attribute1, still something needs to be picked up from the group - but based on Attribute2 and Attribute3.

Comment: You need to decide on the DBMS you use. This kind of query will be very different depending on the features of the database engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Postgresql:

```
select distinct on (name) *
from t
order by name, attribute1 desc, attribute2 desc, attribute3 desc
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Thanks so much. Unbelievably simply it is in postgres.